# Why 3 masters and 3 workers are needed to set a HA k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, distributed-computing, scalability, high-availability

I am learning kubernetes by following the official documentation and in the *[Creating Highly Available clusters with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)* part it's recommended to use 3 masters and 3 workers as a minimum required to set a HA cluster.

This recommendation is given with no explanation about the reasons behind it. In other words, why a 2 masters and 2 workers configuration is not ok with HA ?

Comment: Clustering is quorum based. K8 Stores state in etcd. https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/faq.md#why-an-odd-number-of-cluster-members

Comment: hmm ok.. I didn't understood this sentence : Although adding a node to an odd-sized cluster appears better since there are more machines, the fault tolerance is worse since exactly the same number of nodes may fail without losing quorum but there are more nodes that can fail..

Comment: I think this blog explains odd numbers in a quorum better ,https://medium.com/@bikas.katwal10/why-zookeeper-needs-an-odd-number-of-nodes-bb8d6020e9e9

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/a-closer-look-at-etcd-the-brain-of-a-kubernetes-cluster-788c8ea759a5.    This explains why etcd should have odd number - raft algorithm...

Comment: I think the best way to understand why 3 masters is to know how the raft algorithm works. There is an awesome example here: http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/. This will give you a very clear understanding. Etcd uses the raft algorithm. 

Your worker count does not really matter. You could have one. But for failure, best to have 3+ nodes. Masters generally have uneven numbers to have a proper quorum (already explained). Once you know how raft works, you'll also get a better understanding of proper quorum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an uneven number of master eligible nodes, so you can form a proper quorum (two out of three, three out of five). The total number of nodes doesn't actually matter. Smaller installation often make the same node master eligible and data holding at the same time, so in that case you'd prefer an uneven number of nodes. Once you move to a setup with dedicated master eligible nodes, you're freed from that restriction. You could also run 4 nodes with a quorum of 3, but that will make the cluster unavailable if any two nodes die. The worst setup is 2 nodes since you can only safely run with a quorum of 2, so if a node dies you're unavailable.

(This was an answer from [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11991639) which I think is a good explanation)

Comment: This is a general answer about distributed computing. The question is specific to k8s: Why an odd number of nodes (masters and workers) is needed in a k8s cluster

Comment: K8s is quorum based, therefore even though this answer the wider distributed computing reason, it still holds true for k8s?

Comment: I accepted the answer, but it was about control plane nodes... Why 3 workers are also needed ?

Comment: I dont beleive your workers need to conform to this, I think the 3 worker nodes is just suggested, you will often come accross clusters running even number of worker nodes, think 3 is just enough to run a normal sized workload (depending on node size)

Comment: You can have a single worker on Kubernetes but it's better to have at least three in case of node failure as the cluster will have to redispatch pods from the failing node to the two nodes still available.

Comment: @farhawa check this: https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/faq/#why-an-odd-number-of-cluster-members

Answer (score 0):

This why exactly:

https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/faq/#why-an-odd-number-of-cluster-members

check then the concept of quorum, you can find plenty of info especially in the pacemaker/corosync documentation